# Sorted Array Distinct Values Sum to Target

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am currently working on this coding problem for class.

Given a sorted array of `n` distinct values as well as a target value `T`, determine in `O(n)` time whether or not there exist two distinct values in the array that sum to `T`. (For example, if the array contained `3`, `5`, `6`, `7`, and `9` and `T = 14`, then the method you are to write should return `true`, since `5+9 = 14`. It should return `false` if for the same array of values `T = 17`.)

So, initially, I just wrote the problem with a nested linear search approach which obviously results in a `O(n^2)` runtime to establish a baseline to simplify from, however, I have only been able to, so far, simplify it to `O(n log(n))`. I did this by creating a new array made up of the differences of the `Target - array[i]` and then comparing the new array to the original array using a binary search nested within a loop that linearly goes up the new array.

I am not asking for an answer but rather a hint at where to look to simplify my code. I feel like the fact that the array is sorted is important in getting it down to `O(n)` but not sure how to go about doing it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: i don't see any code.....

Comment: Please post the relevant code. This could help us find bugs or alternate solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have two pointers (s, e) wich set on start and end of you array.

If you will move them in opposite direction (with specific algorithm) and look at the summ of elements you will see that moving one pointer increase summ and moving other decrease.

Onli thing you need is find balance.

If it doesnt help. Ask for next tip.

Comment: Tip? You posted the whole solution more or less.

Comment: @David Eisenstat actually no. I made one mistake (unintentionally)

Answer (score 1):

A Hint:

Something like Binary Search, start with middle (compare with middle)

```
we have startindex = 0, endindex = N-1

while(some condition){
   middleindex = endindex - startindex / 2, middle = array[middleindex]
   if T - array[middleindex] > middle, startindex = middleindex
   if T - array[middleindex] < middle, endindex = middleindex
}
```

It will do the task in O(log(n)) :D

Answer (score 1):

Some tips/steps:

1 - Start the iteration by the `array[i]`, which is the nearest lower value from `T`
2 - Move another pointer to the `array[0]`
3 - Sum both values and compare with `T`
4 - If bigger or if lower, do appropriate moving in the pointers and repeat the step 3